# Adding include directories from a different subdirectory in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake project which has a structure like:

```
project-root
|-external
| |-CMakeLists.txt
| |-libA
|   |-include
|     |-a.h
|-src
| |-CMakeLists.txt
| |-partX
|   |-CMakeLists.txt
|   |-X.cpp
|   |-X.h
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

project-root/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake-minimum-required(VERSION 3.19.2)

project(myProject)
add_subdirectory(external)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

external/CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(libA/include)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(partX)
```

partX/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(X X.cpp X.h)
```

The problem is that, while linking, X.cpp is not able to find a.h
Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: Any reason of you have multiple "CMakeLists.txt" files? Is this easier to change later?

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use `include_directories` in new code. Use `target_include_directories` and `target_link_libraries` to declare include paths and dependencies. That involves updating two of your files:

```
# ./external/CMakeLists.txt

add_library(libA INTERFACE)

# IMPORTANT
target_include_directories(libA INTERFACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libA/include")
```

```
# ./src/partX/CMakeLists.txt

add_library(X X.cpp X.h)

# IMPORTANT
# If X uses symbols from libA in its API, replace PRIVATE with PUBLIC below.
target_link_libraries(X PRIVATE libA)
```

The important parts here are:

1. We're modeling `libA` as an `INTERFACE` library.
2. We can specify through the `target_include_directories(libA INTERFACE ...)` command that targets that link to `libA` need to see `libA`'s include paths.
3. We link `libA` to `X` in order to get the right include paths.

Comment: What is reason of avoiding "include_directories"?

Comment: @CloudCho - For the last ~10 years or so, CMake has favored a target-centric view of compilation. I can't put the full story in the comments but look up "modern CMake" and you will find a wealth of resources that show how it works.

Comment: But it basically boils down to the same reason as "why avoid global variables?"... because it's brittle and behaves in unpredictable ways.